# how do i fill in missing ages in an age pyramid graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data.frame with age and gender information like this:

```
 +-----+--------+
 | age | gender |
 +-----+--------+
 |  48 | male   |
 |  35 | male   |
 |  25 | female |
 |  75 | female |
 |  36 | male   |
 |  49 | female |
 |  21 | male   |
 |  61 | female |
 |  18 | female |
 +-----+--------+
```

a similar data frame can be generated using this code:

```
data <- data.frame(age=sample(18:80,120,replace=T), gender=c('male','female'))
```

I want to show this data in an age pyramid graph using ggplot. Problem is, not all ages are represented in my data. For my overview, it is important that the x-axis has a constant tick size. I tried using the scale_x_discrete parameter, but that does not fill in empty lines. This is the code that i've used so far:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = as.factor(age), fill = gender)) +
  geom_bar(data = subset(data, gender == "female")) +
  geom_bar(data = subset(data, gender == "male"), mapping = aes(y = - ..count.. ), position = 
"identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = abs) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = seq(18, 80, 1), labels = abs(seq(18,80, 1))) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

as you can see, age lines at for example age = 59 are missing. Is there any way of making this axis evenly spaced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could count how many of each exist in the data and then use `tidyr::complete` to add any missing combinations:

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(age=sample(18:80,120,replace=T), gender=c('male','female')) %>%
  count(age, gender) %>%
  complete(age = 18:80, gender, fill = list(n=0)) %>%
  mutate(n = if_else(gender == "male", -n, n)) %>%

  ggplot(aes(x = age, n, fill = gender)) +
  geom_col() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = abs) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 18:80, minor_breaks = NULL, expand = c(0,0)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

(Upon reflection, a shorter method that might be enough would be to employ a continuous x scale, such that all ages are enumerated, regardless of appearance in the data. e.g. `scale_x_continuous(breaks = 18:80, minor_breaks = NULL, expand = c(0,0)) +`)